# html dynamic border around element

Tags: html, css, border

can't find neat solution..Let's say I have some text I'd like to wrap with some border.

```
<p>Some Text</p>
```

The thing is what I do in css the border it draws it until the end of the line, and I want it only on my text and that's it. Is there some neat solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.textborder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

A display inline-block on the `p` tag should do the trick for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/qf7cs53v/

Answer (score 1):

Your element is "block" type by default. You should use the `display` css proprety to change the behaviour of this element in order to have border only around the text and not all the page.

```html
<p style = "display : inline; border : solid 1px black"> test </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a `width` to the p element

http://jsfiddle.net/xu2f2Ldr/